# the sql query is giving me a single row using like query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

```
Id  Account_name      Date         Debit    Credit    
1   revenue         2014-05-05    808001    555001      
2   expense         2014-05-05     48000     90000      
3   a/p             2014-05-05       800      1000       
3   a/r             2014-05-05     36000     50000        
4   rent_revenue    2014-05-05     40000     50000
```

ok this is my table I want to calculate the total balance of revenue, `a/r`and the sql query is below given

```
SELECT account_name, SUM(debit)+SUM(credit) AS TOTAL BALANCE 
WHERE  account_name LIKE '%revenue%'
```

The problem is that its only showing me the result of `account_name='revenue'` and its total balance, I want the other row as well what should I do ?

Comment: you're using aggregate functions without a `group by` clause. that's not exactly valid.

Comment: ok what should i do then ?

Comment: `group by account_name`

Comment: I think you just want `debit + credit`

Comment: You need to put backticks around `TOTAL BALANCE`, since the alias contains a space.

Comment: This one is a bit tricky, because the Balance is "not" the sum of debit and credit. Depending which account you're referring to, is either SUM( credit - debit ) or SUM( debit - credit )

Comment: It's just a group by that's needed.

Comment: There is no `FROM` clause in this statement. If you add it in (please copy and paste the whole statement you have tried) then I will undownvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this :

```
SELECT account_name ,SUM(debit)+SUM(credit) AS `TOTAL BALANCE`
FROM Tablename
WHERE account_name LIKE '%revenue%' 
GROUP BY account_name
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE account_name LIKE '%revenue%' GROUP BY account_name' at line 2

Comment: yeah I took your sql statement and added the missing group by, but you are missing FROM tablename in your statement, so that's also missing in my answer. I updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, try this..

```
SELECT account_name 
,SUM(debit)+SUM(credit) AS `TOTAL BALANCE`
 WHERE
 Right(account_name,7) = 'revenue'
 GROUP BY account_name
```

Comment: `TOTAL BALANCE` will not work unless it is surrounded by backticks, since it contains a space.

Comment: That is fine..  You can use the backticks..  The main point I was trying to leverage is the use of RIGHT in the WHERE clause.  The LIKE is an expensive command in SQL.

Comment: Of course, but if your example doesn't work, it may cause the OP (or a future reader) some confusion. My view is that goes for any answer on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT account_name , debit+credit AS TOTAL_BALANCE WHERE account_name LIKE '%revenue%'
```

Comment: This doesn't combine all the transactions for the same account.

Comment: Please elaborate why you think this is a valid answer, instead of just dropping some code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the sum of debit and credit returned for each account, you may use

```
-- sum of debit and credit for each group of accounts that share the same name and match the pattern
SELECT account_name, 
    SUM(debit) + SUM(credit) AS TOTAL_BALANCE 
FROM ACCOUNTS 
WHERE account_name LIKE '%revenue%'
GROUP BY account_name
```

or simply

```
-- sum of debit and credit for each account that matches the pattern 
SELECT account_name, 
    debit + credit AS TOTAL_BALANCE 
FROM ACCOUNTS 
WHERE account_name LIKE '%revenue%'
```

, which gets along without the group by.

If you want both the sum over all accounts that match the pattern and the pattern to be returned in the result set, you must somehow include your patterns in the group by clause. For example

```
-- returns the respective sums over all debits and credits with the same last 7 signs in their names, as far as the match the pattern in the where clause
SELECT RIGHT(Account_Name, 7) acc_name_tr, 
    SUM(debit) + SUM(credit) AS TOTAL_BALANCE 
FROM Accounts23525506 
WHERE Account_Name LIKE '%revenue%'
GROUP BY RIGHT(Account_Name, 7)
```

The last statement should yield

```
acc_name_tr TOTAL_BALANCE
revenue 1453002
```

Yet I changed your pattern to »account_name ends with 'revenue'«, so be careful about whether the group-by-pattern still matches your purpose.

Answer (score -1):

Use Group By on account_name and then put restrictions on output using having clause.

```
SELECT   account_name, SUM(debit+credit) AS [TOTAL BALANCE] 
FROM     Tablename 
GROUP BY account_name  
HAVING   account_name LIKE '%revenue%' .
```

Comment: Is the `[]` syntax valid for MySQL? I think that might be only suitable for SQL Server.